# My data won't pass to MongoDB from ReactJS, but I don't get any errors as to why...?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

Before this, I got a notice saying that 'quote' was undefined, but I changed all of the variables to quote, author, creator, and tags from newQuote, newAuthor, etc. and it stopped.

My index.js

```
uri = mongo URL I have checked a hundred times...and it connects to 

mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })    
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
    .catch(console.error);;

const Quote = require("./models/Quote");

app.get('/quotes', async (req, res) => {
    const quotes = await Quote.find();
    res.json(quotes);
});

app.post('/quote/new', (req, res) => {
    const quote = new Quote({
    quote: req.body.quote,
        author: req.body.author,
        creator: req.body.creator,
        tags: req.body.tags
    })

    quote.save();
console.log("Post created.");
    res.json(quote);
});

app.delete('/quote/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await Quote.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
    res.json({result});
});


app.put('/quote/update/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const quote = await Quote.findById(req.params.id);

    quote.quote = req.body.quote;
        quote.author = req.body.author;
        quote.creator = req.body.creator;
        quote.tags = req.body.tags;

    quote.save();

    res.json(quote);
});
```

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Quote = new Schema({
    quote: String,
        author: String,
    creator: String,
    tags: String,
});

module.exports = new mongoose.model("quote", Quote);
```

My App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
// import About from'./components/About.jsx';
// import Welcome from './components/Welcome.jsx';
// import SavedImages from './components/SavedImages.jsx';
// import ImageCreator from './components/ImageCreator.jsx';
import Quote from'./components/Quote.jsx';
const urilocal = "http://localhost:4444";


//Import Components

function App() {
    const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
    const [quote, setNewQuote] = useState("");
    const [author, setNewAuthor] = useState("");
    const [creator, setNewCreator] = useState("");
    const [tags, setNewTags] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        GetQuotes();
    }, []);

    const GetQuotes = () => {
        fetch(urilocal + '/quotes')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setQuotes(data))
            .catch((err) => console.error("Error: ", err));
    }

    const addQuote = async () => {
        const data = await fetch(urilocal + "/quotes/new", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json" 
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                quote: quote,
                author: author,
                creator: creator,
                tags: tags
            })
        }).then(res => res.json());

        setQuotes([...quotes, data]);

        setNewQuote("");
        setNewAuthor("");
        setNewCreator("");
        setNewTags("");
    }

    // const deleteQuote = async id => {
    //  const data = await fetch(urilocal + '/quote/delete/' + id, { method: "DELETE" }).then(res => res.json());
    //  setQuotes(quotes => quotes.filter(quote => quote._id !== data.result._id));
    // }

  return (

      <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">

      
<form>
<h3>Add Quote</h3>

        
<input type="text" className="add-quote-input" onChange={e => setNewQuote(e.target.value)} value={quote} placeholder="Quote" name="quote"/>

      <br/>
   
                <input type="text" className="add-quote-input" onChange={e => setNewAuthor(e.target.value)} value={author} placeholder="Author" name="author" />

          <br/>
      
                <input type="text" className="add-quote-input" onChange={e => setNewCreator(e.target.value)} value={creator} placeholder="Creator" name="creator"/>
          
      <br/>
        
                <input type="text" className="add-quote-input" onChange={e => setNewTags(e.target.value)} value={tags} placeholder="Tags" name="tags"/>
                        <br/>
      <button onClick={addQuote}>Add Quote</button>
    </form>             



          <div className="quotes">
        {quotes.length > 0 ? quotes.map(quote => (
                    
                 <Quote quote={quote.quote} author={quote.author} />
            
    // <div className="delete-quote" onClick={() => deleteQuote(quote._id)}>x</div>
                    
        )) : (
        <><p>You currently have no quotes</p></>
        )}
    </div>

                     
  </header>
</div>
);

}


export default App;
```

I was expecting MongoDB to receive the information.

I tried to change the variables and double check my Schema.

Comment: `quote.save()` is asynchronous, does using await help?